# Change a text input's value with CSS?

Tags: css

Is there anyway to change a text input's value (the default text that displays) with CSS?

I'm optimizing a site for mobile and I want the text 'search this site' to be shortened to 'search'.

Comment: have you considered using Javascript to detect the users browser and change the fields? 
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_browser.asp

Comment: @Waltzy - don't detect the browser itself; it's bad practice. Instead, detect the browser's capabilities using tools like Modernizr; it's more reliable and gives you more fine-grained control. There are a very few cases where browser detection is necessary because other techniques don't work, but this isn't one of them.

Comment: @Spudley Cheers for the heads up, I'll bear it in mind.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That really isn't what CSS is for.

CSS is for styling your content; HTML is for the actual content itself.

If you need to modify the content after the HTML has loaded, then that's what Javascript is for.

So the real answer to your question is: either modify the HTML directly, or use Javascript.

There are some things you *can* do with CSS that affect the content, such as adding additional text in-front of or behind an element using the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-selectors, but that won't help you in this case, and shouldn't be used for the kind of content change work that you're talking about.

By the way, slightly off-topic, but if you're using input field value as a prompt text, you may want to consider looking into the HTML5 `placeholder` attribute instead. This also doesn't address your question, but it does sound like it might be something that could be useful to you.

Comment: Well, if you *completely* ignore the CSS `content` property, I suppose that's true.

Comment: @RubenMartinezJr.: I didn't ignore `content`; it only applies for selectors like `:before` and that is in the answer. But the point is that even though you can do it, you shouldn't: putting significant content into CSS is a bad practice. It muddies the separation between style and content that CSS was designed for, and it has usability issues for end users (eg it can't be copy+pasted, it doesn't get read by screen readers for blind users, etc). Bottom line is that the `content` property in `:before` and `:after` should only be used for spot effects, not for actual site content.

Answer (score 8):

No, CSS cannot change the `value` attribute of an `input`, or indeed any attribute of any element.

Answer (score 5):

Late to the party but using "content" attribute, within `element:before` will accomplish what you need as seen in http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_content_string

I was able to manipulate a button content value via jQuery toggleClass, switching between the following classes:

```
.open_button:before{
    content:"open";
}
.close_button:before{
    content: "close";
}
```

I understand the qualms, but I do feel like toggleClass provides an elegance that justifies the CSS trick.  Otherwise one would be using a toggle function with nested css switch functions.  I personally think avoiding the nested jQuery functions is better looking.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the value use the HTML "value" attribute;

example:

```
<input type="submit" value="ENVIAR">
```

that will change the default "submit" value to "enviar"

Answer (score 2):

For me the solution was

```
<button type="submit" class="mybutton" name="add">
   <span class="add">Add new</span>
</button>
```

therefore the css will be :

```
.mybutton:hover .add:after{content="0"}
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution is little bit tricky,

but it's always work for me.

```css
/*CSS Code*/

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
.showondesktop {
display: none !important; }
}

#showonmobile {
    display:none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    #showonmobile {
display:block; }
}
```

```html
<!--HTML Code->

<div class="showondesktop"> search this site </div>

<div id="showonmobile"> search </div>
```

When the website is visited from Mobile it will be displayed "**search**", but when visited from Desktop it will be displayed "**search this site**".

**Image Preview:**

[Output-Desktop-view.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqzsS.jpg)

[Output-Mobile-view.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wm34H.jpg)

Answer (score -6):

so easy, just type in for example:

```css
button {
 color: red;
 font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

there you are, 
the buttons take all the inputs with values with for example submit/reset/.etc..

Comment: He doesn't want to change color and font.