# How to limit the number of characters displayed inside input text?

Tags: php, css, input, maxlength

I have a PHP string I CANT CHANGE that produces an input with a date like this:

```
<input type="text" value="2016-07-12 00:00:00" maxlength="10">
```

I dont need the 00:00:00 part so I used maxlength to cut it off but it still displays. What I can do to take it off? I cant change the PHP so I have to rely on CSS and HTML solutions only.

Comment: You need javascript to do that. CSS is not for that purpose.

Comment: Where this string come from ? I think you'll need some jQuery in order to slice the string.

Comment: Its PHP that produces the entire input code just like in my example.

Comment: You can use something like `substr($string, 0, 9)` and then you can set in input textbox.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to achieve this using CSS then read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672521/change-a-text-inputs-value-with-css).

Using javascript you can achieve this by following methods:

```js
var val = document.getElementById("myDate").value;
document.getElementById("myDate").value = val.substring(0, val.indexOf(" "));
```

```html
<input type="text" value="2016-07-12 00:00:00" maxlength="10" id="myDate">
```

```js
var val = document.getElementById("myDate").value;
document.getElementById("myDate").value = val.split(" ")[0];
```

```html
<input type="text" value="2016-07-12 00:00:00" maxlength="10" id="myDate">
```

```js
var val = document.getElementById("myDate").value;
var maxLen = 10;
document.getElementById("myDate").value = val.substring(0,maxLen);
```

```html
<input type="text" value="2016-07-12 00:00:00" maxlength="10" id="myDate">
```

Comment: Thanks for your elaborated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Set id or any selector to your text box and place below js code.

document.getElementById("dateField").value = new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 10);