# How To Change Button Value Text in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am looking and searching thru your posts related to my concerns but I could not find it. Furthermore, I write this to ask you for different cases:

Condition right now:

```
<input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wppb-submit" class="button button-primary" value="LOGIN">
```

My question is, I want to change its value with CSS since I cannot go to HTML file:

How to change its `"value="LOGIN"`to be `"value="ENTER"`

Please help since I tried to follow some articles here but still failed.

Many thanks.

Razka

Comment: in CSS is not possible, Maybe you could try to play with a pseudoelement if it was an _actual_ `button` element.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change a text input's value with css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672521/change-a-text-inputs-value-with-css)

Comment: why can't you go to the html? this would ideally be done in JavaScript

Answer (score 2):

CSS expresses the presentation of structured documents, as it is a **Style** Sheet. You will not be able to modify the HTML value tag with it.